References on probability divergence
I am learning Markov chains, CTMP, SDEs. I am especially interested in the convergence analysis or mixing time. I notice that in many papers, they use many kinds of divergence to measure the distance, such as $\chi^2$, $KL$, $TV$....
Is there a book systematically introducing the properties and relation of these divergence?
